# Closures - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Because callbacks behave as if they are actually placed inside a function, they are in practice closures: they can access the containing function’s variables and parameters, and even the variables from the global scope [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-closures-callbacks-iifes/). Right? But if I do:

```
function fullName(firstName, lastName, callback){
 var f_scope = "X";
  console.log("My name is " + firstName + " " + lastName);
  callback(lastName);
}

var greeting = function(ln){
  console.log('Welcome Mr. ' + ln);
  console.log(f_scope);//<<---error

};

fullName("Jackie", "Chan", greeting);
```

In other hand if `greeting` was inside of `fullName` the error will not happen. So callbacks are not 100% like if they are placed inside of a function? Right?

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: "So callbacks are not 100% like if they are placed inside of a function." --- callbacks 100% like they were **not** placed inside of a function. Your whole question (there is no one actually though) starts with a wrong assumption. Everything else is based on it and is incorrect as well.

Comment: Scoping is **static**. What matters is the context in which the function is defined, not the context in which it's called. It's called *lexical scoping* because what matters is the textual context of the function definition itself. When references to the function are passed around at runtime, they retain access to the *lexical* - source code - context, but it's not modified dynamically based on the environment when the function is called.

Comment: Closures and scope are confusing to newbies, I recommend you spend some time reading about them.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> they can access the containing function’s variables and parameters

*Lexically* containing. They can access the variables from the scope in which the function is defined, not those from the scope where it is called. Functions in JS do form [lexical closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), there is **no [dynamic scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping)**.

That `f_scope` variable is neither a global variable nor declared in a function that contains `greeting`.

Answer (score 1):

> Because callbacks behave as if they are actually placed inside a function

Callbacks defined inside a function behave as if they were defined inside a function. Callbacks defined outside a function behave as if they were defined outside a function.

> they are in practice closures

They *are* closures, in theory *and* in practice. What differs is what they close over.

```
var x = 1;
function externalCallback() {
  // closes over x, someFunction, externalCallback
}
function someFunction() {
  var y = 2;
  var internalCallback = function() {
    // closes over x, someFunction, externalCallback, internalCallback, y
  }
  setTimeout(externalCallback, 0);
  setTimeout(internalCallback, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example:

```
function callback_caller(callback) {
    var x = 7;
    callback();
}

function func1() {
    var y = 9;
    function inner_func() {
        // console.log('x', x); // <-- this would not work
        console.log('y', y);    // <-- this is ok
    }
    return inner_func;
}

var callback = func1();
callback_caller(callback); // prints: y 9
```

At the time when `inner_func` gets called, `func1`, which contains variable `y` is long gone, but still `inner_func` can access it. That is because `y` is in the closure.

On the other hand, `x` has nothing to do with `inner_func` and is never available there.

Answer (score 0):

fullName is at root context, so it can see itself and "greeting".

fullName then creates "f_scope" which is only visible inside fullName.

root context calls fullName with firstName, lastName, callback. The firstName and lastName are only available inside of the fullName context, as params are local/private variables of the function.

fullName then calls callback, which accepts a param, ln, which happens to be the lastName param/variable in fullName, but this is passed as a param, not access directly.

f_scope is private to fullName, therefore, you cannot call it inside greeting, you can pass it to greeting if you make it a parameter of the function.